# Turning off SSL certificate check when adding PPAs

Tags: apt

I'm on an enterprise network where my traffic is man-in-the-middled. With `pip` I'm able to do `--no-check-certificate`.

How can I do this for adding PPAs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no option to disable checking of certificates for `add-apt-repository`, and the URL is hard-coded. You can change it, but it will be lost the next time `python3-software-properties` is upgraded. Edit `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py` and change `LAUNCHPAD_PPA_API` to `'http://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~%s/+archive/%s'`:

```
sudo sed -i.bak '/^LAUNCHPAD_PPA_API = /s/https/http/' /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py
```

---

The PPA repository URLs themselves are not be HTTPS. You can fetch the key yourself. So, you can add the PPA manually. For example, for the [GNOME3 PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3), expand the section named *Technical details about this PPA*. You'll see something like this:

[image]

The URL seen there is what you actually need. Using it, you can add the repository yourself:

```
printf "%s http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main\n" deb deb-src | 
  sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gnome3-ppa.list
```

Click on the link underneath **Signing Key**, and you'll be taken to the GPG key for this repo. If the link doesn't work because of a firewall/proxy, etc. (it's on a non-standard port), you can go to http://keyserver.ubuntu.com, and manually search for `0x3B1510FD` (`0x` followed by the key fingerprint), select [the public key (aka `pub`)](http://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0xF1773AF13B1510FD), and copy the text from the begin line to the end. Then do:

```
sudo apt-key add -
```

and paste the key. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to complete adding the key. Done!