# How Do I Use Apt with an Offline Mirror of a PPA Repository?

Tags: apt, ppa, repository, offline

I'm a Linux noob but a longtime Windows/DOS user.
I'm running Ubuntu Trusty on an air-gap network (see below).

As a baseline, I'm already able to use APT with an offline Ubuntu repository to install anything that's available in the Ubuntu repos: main, universe, etc. My offline Ubuntu repository is stored on a USB hard drive. I'm having difficulty doing the same thing with a PPA repository.

My setup is:

A. Windows 7 PC connected to Internet through corporate network.
B. Ubuntu (Trusty) PC on "air-gap" network.

I want to use APT to install KiCad 4 (h++p://kicad-pcb.org/download/ubuntu/) on my air-gap Ubuntu PC.

**I've done the following on the Windows PC:**
 1. I setup pyapt-mirror, h++ps://launchpad.net/pyapt-mirror, on my
    Windows PC.
 2. I pointed pyapt-mirror to the KiCad repo:
    h++p://ppa.launchpad.net/js-reynaud/kicad-4/ubuntu trusty main
 3. I ran pyapt-mirror and successfully downloaded the PPA to my Windows PC.
 4. I copied the local mirror from my Windows PC to a USB hard drive.

**I've done the following on the Ubuntu PC:**
5. Moved the USB hard drive to my Ubuntu PC and used 'tree -d' to confirm that the PPA is visible:

```
/media/<user>/<volname>/ppa.launchpad.net/js-reynaud/kicad-4/ubuntu
├── dists
│   └── trusty
│       └── main
│           └── binary-amd64
└── pool
    └── main
        ├── k
        │   ├── kicad
        │   ├── kicad-doc
        │   ├── kicad-i18n
        │   └── kicad-library
        └── w
            ├── wxpython3.0
            └── wxwidgets3.0
```

6. I created the sources list file like this:

   sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list
7. In that file, I added this string (the only string in the file):

   deb file:///media///ppa.launchpad.net/js-reynaud/kicad-4/ubuntu trusty main

Note that I opened Ubuntu Software Center and selected Edit -> Software Sources… -> Other Software.. and I can see my new entry:

```
file:///media/<user>/<volname>/ppa.launchpad.net/js-reynaud/kicad-4/ubuntu trusty main
```

8. In a terminal I typed:

   sudo add-apt-repository –yes ppa:js-reynaud/kicad-4

After a few seconds it responds:

> Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:js-reynaud/kicad-4'. Please check that the PPA
>   name or format is correct.

I need some suggestions for what to try next.

Thanks,

-Rob

Comment: I don't know the answer but [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429803/cannot-add-ppa-please-check-that-the-ppa-name-or-format-is-correct) says that this error can be caused by Ubuntu not being able to access the certificate to verify the PPA's digital signature.  Based on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/637775/turning-off-ssl-certificate-check-when-adding-ppas), it seems like you will have to manually get the GPG key for the PPA and add it to your keyring.  This is just a guess.